Transition scale property is not working on a live site but working perfectly locally
This is my website which I have made using tailwind css.
www.designmonsters.io
I am facing a weird problem. On a projects section, I have used a following property on each project:
"transition duration-500 ease-in-out hover:scale-110"
It works perfectly fine locally but on a live site the scaling property is not working.
You can view it using 'view-source'.
I have used this to all 6 projects plus I have also used it on logos slider but it is not working anywhere.
Please help me out.
as I said previously it works perfectly well locally when I use it via vs-code locally.

ease-in-out & scale-110 are not part of the style.css or custom.css. So, As they are either imported nor declared by you, it is not working.

both are the properties in tailwind css and if it is not then how it is working perfectly fine locally?

Not sure why it is working in local. But there seems to be an issue with importing styles. Try comparing the style.css file on local and website.

see this website. I have made it recently and in this website I have used exactly same properties on a projects section but here it is working perfectly. https://rockymountain.designmonsters.io/

It could help if you reproduced the problem in a very simple example in a repl, like https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/. That can help narrow down the problem and makes sure that there's nothing else in the project that could be causing the problem.
